# Using CDK to Create a Step Function With Dependencies on Other AWS Resources (Like a Lambda) Owned By Different Projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

We're using AWS Step Functions in our application. We have one step function we're creating with the use of the CDK as part of a deployment of Application A from Repository A. That step function needs to include a lambda function as one of the steps. The problem we're having is that this lambda function is created and maintained independently in a different repository (Repository B). We're not sure the best way to connect one AWS resource (AWS Lambda) with another AWS resource (AWS Step Functions) when the creation of those two resources is happening independently in two different places.

We'd like to not manually create the lambda or step function (or both) in each environment. It's time consuming, prone to error and we're going to have a lot of these situations occur.

Our best thought at the moment is that we could *maybe* have Application A create the step function, but have it create and reference an empty lambda. Initially the step function won't be fully functional of course, but then when we deploy Application B it could look for that empty lambda function and upload new code to it.

And, so that we don't have an issue where deploying Application B first results in non-working code. We can also handle the opposite condition: Application B could create the lambda function before uploading the code to it if it doesn't already exist. Application A could then look to see if the lambda function already exists when creating the step function and just reference the lambda function in the step function directly.

Concerns with this approach:

- This is extra work and adds a lot of complexity to the deployment, so more potential for failure
- I'm not sure I can easily look up a lambda function like this anyway (I guess it would have to be by name since we couldn't know what the ARN would be when we're writing the code). But then we have issues if the name changes too, so maybe there's a pre-defined ID or something we could use to look it up instead.
- Potential for code failing in production. If when deploying to QA for testing we deploy Application A, then Application B, we really only know that scenario works. If, then, when going to production we deploy them in the opposite order it might break.

What are some good options for this kind of thing because I can't think of anything great. My best idea involves not using lambda at all but instead having the step function step be queueing something up in SQS, then Application B can just read from that queue no problem. It feels like this is a common enough scenario though that there must be some clean way to do it with lambda and I wouldn't want my decisions on what service type I can use in AWS be stymied by deployment feasibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily include an existing Lambda function in a new CDK-created Step Function.  Use the `Function.fromFunctionArn` static method to [get a read-only reference to the Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda-readme.html#imported-lambdas) using its ARN.  The CDK uses the ARN to add the necessary `lambda:InvokeFunction` permissions to the Step Functions' assumed role.

```js
import { aws_stepfunctions_tasks as tasks } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

const importedLambdaTask = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, 'ImportedLambdaTask', {
  lambdaFunction: lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(
    this,
    'ImportedFunc',
    'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:My-Lambda5C096DFA-RLhGGzBJSnMN'
  ),
  resultPath: '$.importedLambdaTask',
});
```

If you prefer not to hard code the Lambda ARN int the CDK stack, save the ARN to a [SSM Parameter Store Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-su-create.html).  Then import it into the stack by name and pass it to `fromFunctionArn`:

```js
const lambdaArnParam = ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(
  this,
  'ArnFromParamStore',
  'lambda-arn-saved-as-ssm-param'
);
```

Edit:  Optionally add a [Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.triggers-readme.html) construct to your CDK Application A to confirm the existence of the Application B Lambda dependency before deploying.  Triggers are a newish CDK feature that let you run Lambda code *during deployments*. The Trigger Function should return an error if it cannot find the external Lambda, thereby causing Application A's deployment to fail.

Comment: I like the idea of using the parameter store (this is what SSM is, right?) to record the lambda ARN. I still have the issue of what happens if I try to create the step function before the lambda function exists, but I guess in that case we could just skip the creation of the step function and redeploy the application once it has been created? That's not too unworkable, we still do have a problem where we could have working code in test and not production if we deploy the applications in a different order, which isn't great.

Comment: @omatase Yes, SSM Parameter Store Parameters.  Also, I added a tip on how to check external dependencies using a `Trigger`.